# Error in invoking new browser session in Grid2-Selenium RC

Tags: grid, selenium-grid

I am trying to implement Grid2 using Selenium RC.

A able to invoke 1IE and 2FF browsers, but found the test case execution in one browser throws an error as below:

```
     com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: ERROR Server Exception:      
      sessionId should not be null; has this session been started yet?at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.throwAssertionFailureExceptionOrError(HttpCommandProcessor.java:101)
at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.doCommand(HttpCommandProcessor.java:95)
at com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium.mouseOver(DefaultSelenium.java:243)
at Framework.GlobalFunctions.mouseOver(GlobalFunctions.java:1233)
at EmployeeHealth.ProductVariables.EmployeeHealth.SelectSubMenuFromTab(EmployeeHealth.java:109)
at EmployeeHealth.TestScripts.EmployeeHealthRegressionSuite.EdCurrnUtilizModuleSelect(EmployeeHealthRegressionSuite.java:23725)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:691)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:883)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1208)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:758)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:613)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.access$000(SuiteRunner.java:37)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner$SuiteWorker.run(SuiteRunner.java:368)
at org.testng.internal.thread.ThreadUtil$CountDownLatchedRunnable.run(ThreadUtil.java:165)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your client is sending a session ID that doesn't exist on the grid.  Did the session timeout?  Take a look at the grid console to see what it thinks is executing.